# Prioritise html (Angular JS)

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

How to prioritise html or page rendering in an angular-js app? Since just ordering the html is not rendering the page in that order.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) as a way to wait for the page to be rendered and prevent the flash of any uncompiled elements.

Comment: No, I am not asking about this. I am asking about controlling the page rendering process, like how to make sure the elements which are important should be loaded first than the other(in angular).